# Video files thumbnails are not showing in some folders

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

I have 2 folders with identical files, a mix of video files and pictures.
1 folder is on external drive and it shows thumbnail for both videos and pictures.
Second folder is in OneDrive, and it only shows thumbnails for pictures, for videos it only shows icons.

Tried resetting cache and toggling different settings, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could check below settings.

1. Search **file explorer options** in windows search box.

[image]

2. Click on **view** tab.

[image]

3. Make sure that **Always shows icons never thumbnails** is unchecked.
4. Press **windows key + r** together to open **run** command box.
5. Write **sysdm.cpl** in it and click **OK**.

[image]

6. Click on **Advanced** tab.
7. Click on **settings**.

[image]

8. Make sure **Show thumbnails instead of icons** option is checked

[image]

**Onedrive settings**

1. Right click on onedrive icon on the taskbar.
2. Click on **settings**.
3. Navigate to **settings** tab.
4. Make sure that **file on-demand** option is unchecked

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried all of these but still the same result. OneDrive folder shows thumbnail only for pictures, but not for videos.

Comment: Actually, after deleting it from OneDrive and copying over again it started working.